# jQuery slideDown() on child elements only

Tags: javascript, jquery

forgive me in advance, I ride the javascript short bus :(

I have the following code for a `slideDown() / slideUp()` with jQuery on a primary navigation:

```
//jQuery slideDown for menu dropdowns
$('.menu').addClass('js-enabled')

$('.js-enabled li').hoverIntent(function () {
   $(".sub-menu").slideDown('slow');
 }, 
 function () {
   $(".sub-menu").slideUp('slow');
});
```

My problem is that the code is not unique to the `.sub-menu`'s which are children of a given `<li>` ... Can someone tell me how to make the above code specific to the `<li>` element being hovered according to the original `$('.js-enabled li').hoverIntent` target?

***EDIT : Here is the production site, demonstrating the bug where all ".sub-menu"'s are being animated by the effect: http://valeriaentertainment.com.s66112.gridserver.com/ ***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume inside the handler you can reference the current element with `this`. Then you can use [**`.find()`**](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to search for certain descendants:

```
$(this).find(".sub-menu").slideDown('slow');
```

Answer (score 3):

You can pass the current `<li>` element as the `context` argument of the [$()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) function:

```
$(".js-enabled li").hoverIntent(function() {
   $(".sub-menu", this).slideDown("slow");
}, function() {
   $(".sub-menu", this).slideUp("slow");
});
```